# Load UIView from Nib with his subviews in MonoTouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

currently i am loading View that has some subviews 
with the 
`NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("NibName", this, null)` function
but than i manually add the subviews of the loaded view with the 
`this.AddSubviews(this.subview1)`.

how can i load the view from the Nib so i wont need to manually add the subviews to the current view?

EDIT:
now i tried to get the result of the LoadNib function :

`var res = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("ViewX",this,null);`

`var betterRes  = Runtime.GetNSObject(res.ValueAt(0)) as Viewx;`

now "this" has the properties of the sub elements initialized but his view is empty.
and "betterRes" has all the subviews in the view but all the properties of the sub elements are null. 
just to clarify ... each sub element is button or label and has is own view.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what do you want: load the view with outlet or action from nib file to main view, here is a try:

```
//Load the view
var res = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("ViewX",this,null); 
// init your view with IntPtr
var betterRes = new Viewx(res.ValueAt(0)); 
//then use this view as main view
 this.View = betterRes;  //Or add subview: this.View.AddSubView(betterRes);
```

Now some properties in your view should work. 
Hope this help!